# Hard disk not showing up in files but it is shown in "disks" and mount option are not available

Tags: mount, hard-drive, disk, error-handling, devices

Error when I tried the solution given on this website

```
iya@riya-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x09dacbb0

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   976773167   488386583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000170586112 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121122 cylinders, total 1953458176 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x16f2a91f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

riya@riya-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

Comment: `sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt` - you appear to be trying to mount the *device* rather than the *partition* (`/dev/sdb1`)

Comment: What is solution?

Comment: Try `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt` - if that doesn't work, use `parted` or `gparted` or `blkid` to get filesystem type info (since `fdisk` doesn't support GPT partition tables, as noted in the warning messages)